# Find the most frequent data every year in SQL

Tags: sql

**TableA :**

```
Years Data
2000  A
2000  B
2000  C
2000  C
2000  D
2001  A
2001  B
2001  B
2002  B
2002  D
2002  D
```

I want to output:

```
Years Data
2000  C
2001  B
2002  D
```

My solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Years, Data
FROM
(
   SELECT Years, Data, COUNT(*) AS _count
   FROM TableA
   GROUP BY Years, Data
) a1
ORDER BY Years, _count DESC
```

But it have a problem:

> `ORDER BY` items must appear in the select list if `SELECT DISTINCT` is specified.

How do I correct my SQL code?

Comment: For which RDBMS?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your database supports row_number(), you can do it like this:

```
SELECT Years, Data
FROM 
(
    SELECT  Years,
            Data,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Years ORDER BY count(*) DESC) rn

    FROM TableA
    GROUP BY Years, Data
) x
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Years, Data
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/NVF7386)

Comment: Yours is better ;).

Comment: Just shorter... probably will have the same query plan :-)

Comment: But I preferred to use `rank()` instead ;).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select t.Years, t.[Data]
from (
    select *, count(*) cnt
    from TableA
    group by years, [Data]
    ) t
left join (
    select Years, max(cnt) maxCnt
    from (
        select *, count(*) cnt
        from TableA
        group by years, [Data]
    ) t
    group by Years
    ) tt on t.Years = tt.Years   -- tt is a view that gives you max count of each year
where t.cnt = tt.maxCnt          -- you need `years`, `[Data]` that its count is max count
order by years;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7aa27/2)

Another way is to use `rank()` in a DBMS that supports it:

```
;with t as (
    select *, count(*) cnt
    from TableA
    group by years, [Data]
), tt as (
    select *, rank() over (partition by years order by cnt desc) rn
    from t
)
select years, [Data]
from tt
where rn = 1
order by years;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7aa27/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using oracle, you can use the function `STATS_MODE`

```
  select years, stats_mode(data)
    from tablet
group by years;
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions154.htm

Answer (score 0):

Your error is `"ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified."`

This means you have put something in the `ORDER BY` that is not in the `SELECT`.  In this case, **_count DESC is not in the SELECT statement**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Years, Data, _count DESC
FROM
(
   SELECT Years, Data, COUNT(*) AS _count
   FROM TableA
   GROUP BY Years, Data
) a1
ORDER BY Years, _count DESC
```